# How to dereference device_private in struct device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sysfs

I'm working on a driver in Linux.  I'm working on getting some /sys file attributes in place that will make things nicer.  In delivering what these attributes are to tell, the attribute functions must have access to some data that's stored by the driver.  Because of how things appear to be made and stored, I thought I could use the `device_private *p` member of the struct device that comes from device_create().  Basically, it's like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    pDevice = device_create(ahcip_class, NULL, /*no parent*/
            MKDEV(AHCIP_MAJOR, AHCIP_MINOR + i), NULL, /*no additional info*/
            DRIVER_NAME "%d", AHCIP_MINOR + i);
    if (IS_ERR(pDevice)) {
        ret = PTR_ERR(pDevice);
        printk(KERN_ERR "%s:%d device_create failed AHCIP_MINOR %d\n",
                __func__, __LINE__, (AHCIP_MINOR + i));
        break;
    }

    mydevs[i].psysfs_dev = pDevice;

    ret = sysfs_create_group(&pDevice->kobj, &attr_group);
    if (!ret) {
        pr_err("%s:%d failed in making the device attributes\n",
                __func__, __LINE__);
        goto build_udev_quick_out;
    }
}
```

This doesn't yet show the assignment into the `device_private` pointer, but that's where I'm headed.  Each new device made under this class will need the same attributes thus the group.  Here's my single attribute that I'm starting with for "proof of concept"

```
static ahcip_dev *get_ahcip_dev(struct kobject *ko)
{
    ahcip_dev *adev = NULL;
    struct device *pdev = container_of(ko, struct device, kobj);
    if (!pdev) {
        pr_err("%s:%d unable to find device struct in kobject\n",
                __func__, __LINE__);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* **** problem dereferencing p **** */
    adev = (ahcip_dev*)pdev->p->driver_data;
    /* return the pointer anyway, but if it's null, print to klog */
    if (!adev)
        pr_err("%s:%d no ahcip_dev, private driver data is NULL\n",
                __func__, __LINE__);

    /* **** again problem dereferencing p **** */
    return pdev->p->(ahcip_dev*)driver_data; // <--- problem here
}

static ssize_t pxis_show(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr,
        char *buff)
{
    u32 pi = 0;
    ahcip_dev *adev = get_ahcip_dev(kobj);

    /* get_ahcip_dev() will print what happened, this needs to return
     * error code
     */
    if (!adev)
        return -EIO;

    pi = adev->port_index;

    return sprintf(buff, "%08x\n", get_port_reg(adev->hba->ports[pi], 0x10));
}
```

I figured that, since `device_create()` returns a `struct device*` and I'm using that to make the device group, the `struct kobject*` that is coming into `pxis_show` is the member of the device structure made by `device_create`.  If this is true, then I should be able to stuff some private data into that object and use it when the /sys files are accessed.  However, when the lines of code marked above dereference the `p` member I get *dereferencing pointer of incomplete type* from gcc.  I've determined that it's the `struct device_private` member of `struct device` that is incomplete but why?  Is there a different structure I should be using?  This seems to be something truly internally by the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For assign private data for device, you need to use `void *drvdata` parameter to `device_create()`. After creation, data can be accessed via `dev_get_drvdata(pdev)`.

`struct device_private` is internal for device implementation. From description of this structure (`drivers/base/base.h`):

> Nothing outside of the driver core should ever touch these fields.

Comment: I was wondering about that and was beginning to see that I should pass it in as that parameter.  Thank you.